# Matching in a point-free style in F#?

Tags: syntax, f#, pattern-matching, pointfree

Consider this code:

```
type Fruit = Apple | Banana

let totalCost fruits = 
  fruits
  |> Seq.map (fun fruit -> 
    match fruit with
    | Apple -> 0.50
    | Banana -> 0.70
  )
  |> Seq.sum
```

Can I rewrite `totalCost` to be more terse in such a way that the `fruit` identifier is removed?

Something like this:

```
// Not real code
let totalCost fruits = 
  fruits
  |> Seq.map (
    match
    | Apple -> 0.50
    | Banana -> 0.70
  )
  |> Seq.sum
```

Comment: Nitpick: `fruit` is an identifier, not a keyword. Keywords are words with special syntactic meaning, such as `type`, `let`, `fun`, `match` and `with`.

Comment: @glennsl Good catch. Fixed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyword you're looking for is `function`:

```
|> Seq.map ( 
    function
    | Apple -> 0.50 
    | Banana -> 0.70
)
```

`function` gets desugared to `fun x -> match x with`